# How can I programmatically find a users HKEY_USERS registry key using powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, registry

I wonder if there is a way to find a local user's registry key in HKEY_USERS if you know the login-name of that user on the local machine. I want to programmatically add stuff to a specific user's registry keys (Autorun for example), but I only know the username. How can I determine which of the cryptic users in HKEY_USERS actually belongs to a specific username?

Answer (score 32):

```
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:UserName)
$sid = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
```

The above snippet gives you the SID of the logged-in user. This when appended to the HKEY_USERS givs you the right path for that username.

```
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Get-Item "HKU:\${sid}"
```

Comment: Ok, do you know how to programaticaly (PowerShell) load a user hive, like it can be done with regedit.exe ?

Comment: U meant something similar to reg.exe LOAD option?

Comment: @JPBlanc Looks like there's no support in .NET and subsequently PowerShell to do that. You'll have to P/Invoke the Windows API using RegLoadKey(). Check this out - http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/

Comment: Hi,thanks alot for that answer, however, I can find the SID of the other user the way youdescribed, but I get a SID that I cannot see when I open regedit.exe. So the question is how can I finally add or change keys of that user path? Does it have to be somehow explicitly loaded, and if so, how can that be achieved?

Comment: If you do not want a `New-PSDrive` (HKU:), it appears that you can just use `Get-Item Registry::HKEY_USERS\${sid}`.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is not complete, as HKEY_USERS does not contain all the users, just those that are currently active.

You'll need to load the registry hive for the user(s) you want to work with using

```
reg load hku\ThatUserName C:\Users\ThatUserName\NTUSER.DAT
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013466/loading-ntuser-dat-with-powershell) for an example of how to load the registry hive for *all* the user(s).

You can then access the registry for that user with

```
Set-Location HKU:\ThatUserName
```

Or call New-PSDrive to give the user's registry it's own drive, like so:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKThatUser -PSProvider Registry -Root HKU\ThatUserName 
Set-Location HKThatUser:
```

Be sure to unload the registry, and do garbage collection to ensure the hive is released  when done:

```
reg unload hku\ThatUserName
[gc]::collect()
```

See [this post for more info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/69a44242-e60f-4643-92d1-ed7440181b66/load-hive-equivlent-in-powershell?forum=ITCG)

Comment: The part to ensure the hive is released is important. I had to switch the order to `[gc]::collect() [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() reg unload hku\ThatUserName`. Otherwise I get a permission denied error when unloading. If I don't unload it the changes to the registry aren't saved.

Comment: @absynce upvoted but unfortunately not correct answer, the key has to be close regardless if used or not before calling `reg unload` see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3):

This does it for me

```sh
ls 'hklm:software/microsoft/windows nt/currentversion/profilelist' | ? {
  $_.getvalue('profileimagepath') -match 'Steven'
} | % pschildname
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/476bdb6/hku.ps1#L3-L5)