# Loading ntuser.dat with powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I need to check some settings for all users on Windows clients in the network. All users have roaming profiles.

I have written a Powershell script that loads an offline copy of a users' NTuser.dat and reads out the specific keys. Then the file is unloaded and the next one is loaded into the registry.

The problem is that after about 10 users no new files are loaded. When the script is launched again the users still don't load. New users are only after I close the Powershell prompt and open a new one. The script always stalls after about 10 users.

```
$userlist = ls "C:\Temp calls\profiles"
foreach ($user in $userlist){
$username = $user.name
#$username = "ciproda"
reg load "hklm\$username" "C:\Temp calls\profiles\$username\NTUSER.DAT" | Out-Null
...

    Here I check the keys

    ...

[gc]::collect()
start-sleep -s 3
reg unload "hklm\$username"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your section '*Here I check the keys*', are you mounting the hive as a PS drive using something like:

```
new-Psdrive -name <blah> -PSProvider Registry -root <blih>
cd <blah>:
# Some Set-ItemProperty and Get-ItemProperty calls here referring to
# your PSDrive and using PowerShell variables
Remove-PSDrive <blah>
```

If you still have references to some of your PSDrive variables before calling REG UNLOAD, that call might fail. Try to remove all variables that would still refer to your PSDrive through `Remove-Variable`.

Comment: This did help, the used reg keys still stay in my registry, but the new ones are loaded. My script works now, I just need a reboot after running it.

Comment: What type of thing is <blih> ?

Comment: After some research, I can answer my own question: <blih> should be something like "hklm:\$username" in this example